# New material not applying and cannot remove old material

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am modelling a drink can and applied a metallic material to it soon after. This worked fine with zero problems. I then tried to apply a different material (my packaging design) to it, however, the metallic material won't go away no matter what I try and the packaging material will not apply to the model. I have troubleshooted for about 2 hours with no success[image: Screenshot in Blender]

https://pasteall.org/blend/be3caf00271844a19ff7bd190148104d

Comment: Are you sure you've assigned the new material to the object faces? If you have, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes, I selected the specific faces I wanted my packaging to be on and marked them with seams, I have shared my file as well :D

Comment: i don't see any shared file here...

Comment: My bad, here it is:
https://pasteall.org/blend/be3caf00271844a19ff7bd190148104d

Comment: Make sure you plug your UV Map Node into the Vector on the Image texture Node. Did you map the texture to the can?

Comment: I see a pink color, which is the missing image, so it looks like it project the image, not the metallic texture contrary to what your image show, so it's weird

Comment: Are there any immediately obvious fixes? Or will I have to start over?

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume your image is missing because you didn't pack the images into the .blend file before uploading, but looking at the project, all that was required was to select the faces that I wanted, in Edit Mode and THEN click "Assign".

Clicking assign without any faces selected does nothing.

[image]